# How to search a grid for matrices and match patterns?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, search, matrix

[Search matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIC3m.jpg)

I want to search a grid and try to find all possible locations to place game objects on. Game objects are of different sizes.

Constraints: Dark gray tiles of the game objects must be on the black path tiles and gray tiles must be on white tiles as seen in the picture attached.

I already have the code for grid and the black path. Every single cell including the path cells is aware about its neighbouring cells.

What kind of a search algorithm is needed to get the desired result? Thanks.

Comment: Your search pattern is a rectangle with three types of cells 1) Don't Care 2) Gray 3) White.  So you place the upper left cell of you search pattern on every cell in the game board and check for matches.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's homework help. Per the guidelines "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the info. I also thought about a similar approach but could not decide which cell to choose from the pattern. Does it matter which cell? Is upper left cell obligatory or any one will do?

Comment: @Wolfwyrd I am sorry you had this impression. I clearly stated that I had already coded the grid and path. I did not include these codes as they are not relevant to my question. It is not an homework or sth. It is a problem ı encountered in my active project. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The is the basic approach for solution which would require least number of lines of code and probably take the longest amount of time.  This approach would use upper left cell of search pattern and then move through all the cells of the game board.  Then you can improve algorithm to reduce time, but would probably take more lines of code.  Whenever the search pattern lies outside the game board you can automatically say does not match.  The cell used may speed up results but it will vary depending on the shape of the search pattern. On average the cell used should not make a difference.